# Unordered List "merging" via Recursion Function Problem

Tags: javascript, algorithm, list, recursion, unordered

I have following problem:

I have this string, which looks like this:

```
* item1
* item2
** item21
** item22
* item3
** item31
** item32
***item321
* item4
```

This is something like unordered nested list, (that means that, item21 and item22 are subcategories of item 2, etc).

I would like to write in javascript/node.js code, where output is like that

```
array = [
  "item1",
  "item2 item21",
  "item2 item22",
  "item3 item31",
  "item3 item32 item321",
  "item4"
];
```

As you see in output, items that display text, are merged by categories and subcategories.

My idea was use somehow recursive function. Before, I split text to array with newline separator. However, somehow, I stuck in realizing that function.

I will be glad and grateful for any ideas or pseudo-codes/codes. 
Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet to get you started.

Note there was a minor inconsistency with your example input, so I took the liberty of assuming it was a typo. Specifically, your input's second to last line `***item321` is missing a space after the `*`'s. I assumed this was a typo, but if not, feel free to remove the space from my regex.

```js
let input = `
* item1
* item2
** item21
** item22
* item3
** item31
** item32
*** item321
* item4
`;

let lines = input
    .split('\n')
    .filter(a => a)
    .map(line => {
      let [_, stars, value] = line.match(/^(\**) (.*)/);
      return {depth: stars.length, value};
    });

let hierarchy = [];
let output = [];
lines.forEach((line) => {
  if (hierarchy.length && line.depth <= hierarchy[hierarchy.length - 1].depth)
    output.push(hierarchy.map(a => a.value).join(' '));

  while (hierarchy.length && line.depth <= hierarchy[hierarchy.length - 1].depth)
    hierarchy.pop();

  hierarchy.push(line);
});
output.push(hierarchy.map(a => a.value).join(' '));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, yes, it was typo. :)